# ubuntu-16.04 Network keeps interrupting

Tags: 16.04, networking, lts

I 'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My wired and wifi connecton keeps interrupting after few seconds after sometime I start my computer.  Can someone please help me solve this?

Output of `lspci -vnn | grep -e Network -e Ethernet`:

```
02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
```

Comment: you need to provide us an output of this command `lspci -vnn | grep -e Network -e Ethernet` then edit your post and upload the results there

Comment: Here it is. Please if can solve this it would be a great help

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please use the [edit] function to include information into your answer, not use comments for that. I've included your information into your question for now and you can remove your comment. Thank you.